# create a command for wlst

Tags: python, weblogic, wlst

I have to mount a command to execute it to wlst.
when you create a SubDeployment you need to target it to each JMSServer.:

```
set('Targets',jarray.array([ObjectName('com.bea:Name=MyVirtualHost_MS1,Type=VirtualHost'),ObjectName('com.bea:Name=MyVirtualHost_MS2,Type=VirtualHost')], ObjectName))
```

you have to add at the end of the command -->

```
",ObjectName('com.bea:Name='+target+',Type=JMSServer')") for each _JMSServer that you have.
finally you have to add at the end of the command -> "], ObjectName)"
```

this is an example of a command with 3 JMSServers

```
set('Targets',jarray.array([ObjectName('com.bea:Name='+target+,Type=JMSServer'),ObjectName('com.bea:Name='+target+',Type=JMSServer'),ObjectName('com.bea:Name='+target+',Type=JMSServer'),ObjectName('com.bea:Name='+target+',Type=JMSServer'),ObjectName('com.bea:Name='+target+',Type=JMSServer')], ObjectName))
```

but I don't get to substitute target variable for the value in each iteration.

I have used this code:

```
command = "set('Targets',jarray.array([ObjectName('com.bea:Name='+target+,Type=JMSServer')"
command_add = ",ObjectName('com.bea:Name='+target+',Type=JMSServer')"
command_last = "], ObjectName))"
jms = ['JMSServer1','JMSServer2','JMSServer3']
for target in jms:
    command += command_add
final_command = command + command_last
print (final_command)
```

Answer (score 0):

command and command_add should be set in the for loop because they include references to target variable

and

> final_command = command